Machine Learning - classification by multidimensional parameters
I am starting to learn about machine learning.
At first I wanted to learn about the classification methodology and if it seems understandable to me in trivial problems like "classification of irises" (a common example in the network) where the network is trained based on csv data on the basis of:
PAR1, PAR2, PAR3, PAR4, CLASS_LABEL
5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2,  0    

Where simple statistics would work just as well.
However, my problem appears when I try to translate this into some multidimensional data model, e.g. regarding orders (where relations between orders are involved (to fulfill order X, you first have to fulfill Y)) trying to treat a specific day in the calendar (1-365) as a class when such an order should be fulfilled, assuming 8 hours of work per day. The question is, is this the right direction?
Generally, based on the example with irises, I constructed datasets on a similar principle:
TIME_REQUIRED_TO_PROCESS_ORDER, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_ID, ORDER_PROCESS_DAY(CLASS_LABEL)
20,                             02-12-2024, 14214,    89

Only in such a flat structure I cannot reflect the 1:N relationship between orders - the question is how to do it so as not to disrupt machine learning (by multiple records per relation)?
